# How to set sort rules on jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jqgrid

I am using `jqGrid`. One of the columns has the possible values:

```
Poor, Fair, Good, Very Good, Excellent, Ideal
```

But when you sort by this column they are ordered alphabetically like:

```
Excellent, Fair, Good, Ideal, Poor, Very Good
```

Instead of the intuitive order you would expect.

Is there a way to correct this?

#### update

Here is a snippet of the php code for generating the grid:

```
$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
$conn->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$grid = new jqGridRender($conn);


//Class to generate query
require('DiamondSQL.php');
$dsql = new DiamondSQL();

$dsql->diamond_table = "rapnet_diamonds";
$dsql->shape_column = "shape";
$dsql->carat_column = "carat";
$dsql->clarity_column = "clarity";

$dsql->setShapes($_GET['shapes']);
$dsql->setCaratMin($_GET['caratMin'] ? $_GET['caratMin'] : "0");
$dsql->setCaratMax($_GET['caratMax'] ? $_GET['caratMax'] : "5");
$dsql->setClarityMin($_GET['clarityMin'] ? $_GET['clarityMin'] : "FL");
$dsql->setClarityMax($_GET['clarityMax'] ? $_GET['clarityMax'] : "I3");

$qry = $dsql->buildQuery();

$grid->SelectCommand = $qry;
$grid->dataType = 'json';
$grid->setColModel();
$grid->setUrl('myfirstgrid.php');


$grid->setGridOptions(array(
    "caption"=>"Diamonds Found",
    "rowNum"=>200,
    "sortname"=>"diamond_id",
    "hoverrows"=>true,
    "sortable"=>0,
    "scroll"=>1,
    "height"=>300,
    "altRows"=>true,
    "colNames"=> array('ID', 'Shape', 'Carat', 'Clarity', 'Color', 'Cut')
));

$grid->renderGrid('#grid','#pager',true, null, null, true,true);
$conn = null;
```

Comment: Usually (but not always) you sort on the server, not the grid. So you have to explain more about how you're getting your data into the grid.

Comment: @Craig, the sort is built into jqgrid, by clicking the column headers.  Does jqgrid reload from the server when you click them?

Comment: for "server" datatypes like "json" and "xml" the grid will be refreshed with respect of new server request. In case of data paging it can be easy understanded. If you need other behavier you should use `loadonce: true` which changes the datatype to 'local' after the first load from the server. After ther first load data sorting will work locally. To make new refresh of data from the server you have to reset the datatype to "json" or "xml" with respect of `setGridParam` and reload grid with respect of `trigger('reloadGrid')`

Answer (score 2):

How I understand from the context you ask about local data sorting.

Your requirements you can very easy implement using combination of following colModel options:

```
edittype:'select', formatter:'select', sorttype:'int'
```

A working example you can see here http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomLocalSort6.htm. (Please, don't look at the data contain. I just modified another example to have your data)

Another way to implement custom local sorting is usage of `sorttype` as function or `index` as function in the column model. These features exist starting with version 3.8. For details see my post in the trirand forum http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/custom-local-sort-with-respect-of-the-function-as-index/.

Comment: Thank you for showing me an example, however I am loading it as json from the server via php. I just didnt realize it was reloaded from the server when sorted. Please see my updates that shows the php code for generating the grid.

Comment: I don't use PHP for software development, so I can't get you direct advice. But somewhere you should define a SQL statement (see http://ponidi.wordpress.com/2009/11/17/tutorial-jqgrid-1-intro/) with **ORDER BY** part. Inside of `ORDER BY` part you should not use just `$sidx $sord` but make for example an addition JOIN to a table which has two columns: the names like "Poor", "Fair", "Good" and so on and an integer value like ID or Weight, so that sorting by this ID or Weight instead of names "Poor", "Fair" etc will gives you correct sort order.